# Rerouting the SAS logs to a specific location in shell scripting

Tags: shell, sas

I have created a shell script which runs a SAS program which is created log in the same folder where I'm running Shell script. But, I'm trying to save the logs to a specific folder on LINUX. I used -log option and it is throwing me error...I'm running following command in my shell script...

```
/saspath/sas /homesas/test.sas   -log home/sasu1/log/test.log.$rundatetime \
```

I'm getting this error... `-log: command not found`

Comment: What if you run it without all those extra spaces?

Comment: @Joe :those extra spaces are between different commands.../saspath/sas(To invoke SAS)     /homesas/test.sas(My sas Script)   -log home/sasu1/log/test.log.$rundatetime  ..... So, removing spaces doesn't work...

Comment: I see three spaces between `test.sas` and `-log`.  I think that may be a problem.

Comment: try `-log home/sasu1/log/test.$rundatetime.log` Maybe the suffix should be `log`

Comment: What happens if you change the first part to `/saspath/sas -sysin /homesas/test.sas`?

Comment: Spaces should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal Unix convention to put the options (-log) before the parameters (filename) to a command.

```
sas -log xxx.log xxx.sas
```

Your real problem might be that you need to construct your log filename first.

```
pgm=test
log=${pgm}.${rundatetime}.log 
sas -log $log &pgm
```

Another thing to check is that some sites have build scripts to launch SAS and they do not properly pass the command line arguments through to the actual command that launches SAS. Check whether /saspath/sas is the actual command provided by SAS or something your local IT group created.